# Applying weight paint caused my mesh to rotate 90 degrees

Tags: rigging, makehuman

I have been working on a hospital gown for a character that I made. I exported the rig from Makehuman so maybe that could be causing an orientation problem. Whenever I try to parent the gown mesh to the rig it automatically scales my mesh up and rotates it -90 degrees on the X-axis. I tried applying rotation and scale and then finally "all transforms" with "Control + A" but nothing is affected.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work while typing the question. I guess I just didn't have it selected because in Makehuman the mesh has its origin at the very bottom. So I thought I had it selected when I applied the transform. But yeah, I box selected all the meshes that I needed and the rig and apply all transform.